# ORA-22288: file or LOB operation FILEOPEN failed, access denied

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle21c

I would like to store an xml file in oracle database and I did the following :

```
create table MyTab (filename varchar(64), xml XMLType);

create or replace directory XML_DIR as 'C:\Users\XXX\XXX\Folder\xml';

insert into MyTab VALUES ('file.xml', xmltype(bfilename('XML_DIR','file.xml'),nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8')));
```

*However i have this error : ORA-22288: file or LOB operation FILEOPEN failed, **access denied***

**Can someone explain what is wrong, please?**

Comment: You don't have rights for create table

Comment: @Roland when I create the table it works, the problem is when I execute my insert query

Comment: You don't have rights for insert. With Oracle you have grants for everything. Try to get grants for 'All'

Comment: And how can I solve the problem of access rights? I tried to change file.xml permission (ex chmod o+r file.xml) with git bash but it did'nt work (i'm on windows os)

Comment: @Roland i connected with sysdba and i execute this query : Grant all on directory XML_DIR to MyUser; but i still get error

Comment: The account that the DB server runs under does not have access to your C:\Users folder, so it can't access the file there.

Comment: @AhmedK Try right-clicking on the "xml" folder, select Properties, Security, Edit.., Add.., Advanced..., Find Now..., double-click on name like "ORA_OraDB19Home1_SVCACCTS" (will be different depending on how you installed Oracle, I think that "ORA_DBA" may also work for some versions), OK, OK, OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give Oracle permission to use a directory on Windows:

1. Open Windows Explorer
2. Right-click on the relevant folder
3. Click Properties
4. Click Security
5. Click Edit...
6. Click Add...
7. Click Advanced...
8. Click Find Now...
9. Double-click on a name like "ORA_OraDB19Home1_SVCACCTS" (this will be different depending on your version and on how you installed Oracle, and I think that "ORA_DBA" may also work for some versions)
10. Click OK three times